# Validators - some not applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.1

Here is the code from the model. The problem here is that "validates :baggage" validator works like a charm, while "validates :capacity" - doesn't. It doesn't show any error messages, just allows seats to go over the capacity number.
Any ideas as to why one work and the other doesn't?

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :baggage, :numericality => { :less_than_or_equal_to => :baggage_allowance }, :presence => true
  validates :capacity, :numericality => { :less_than_or_equal_to => :capacity }, :presence => true
  belongs_to :flight


  def baggage_allowance
    flight.baggage_allowance
  end  

  def capacity
    flight.capacity
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same method `capacity` to validator and validated.

You should want to say `def flight_capacity` and `:less_than_or_equal_to => :flight_capacity`.

Comment: Hi Elijah. If this solved your problem, can you to mark the answer as "Accepted"? Thanks.